# JSP displaying same data from database even after update

Tags: jsp, dao, dto

My JSP is displaying the same data selected from a mysql database. I use a DAO and DTO for getting this data from the database and display in the JSP but even when I change the data in the database, it still displays the previous data. What could be the problem?

Comment: without code how can we guess

Answer (score 1):

After retriving the data from db have u set data in dao and dto also check if u have given

```
connection.commit();
```

after executing the query .